# Проверить, содержит ли массив два числа?

Tags: java, массивы

Помогите, ломаю голову и не понимаю в чем ошибка

Напишите программу, которая считывает несортированный массив целых чисел и два числа `n` и `m`. Программа должна проверить, находятся ли `n` и `m` рядом друг с другом в массиве (в любом порядке).

```
input 1:
3
1 3 2
2 3

output 1:
true
```

```
input 2:
3
2 1 2
2 3

output 2:
false
```

Вот мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[length];

        boolean broken = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int j = 1; j < length; j++) {

            if (numbers[j] == n && numbers[j - 1] == m || numbers[j] == m && numbers[j + 1] == n || numbers[j] == m && numbers[j - 1] == n || numbers[j] == n && numbers[j + 1] == m) {
                broken = false;
            } else if (numbers[j] != n && numbers[j - 1] != m || numbers[j] != n && numbers[j + 1] != m || numbers[j] != m && numbers[j - 1] != n || numbers[j] != m && numbers[j + 1] != n) {
                broken = true;
            }

        }
        if (broken) {
            System.out.println("false");
        } else {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, у меня нет желания разбираться в логике Ваших условий. Типичная ошибка - присвоение значение булевской переменной на каждой итерации, так что флаг, показывающий, что пара чисел найдена, перепишется на следующей итерации цикла.

```
boolean found = false;
for (int j = 1; j < length; j++) {
  if ((numbers[j-1] == n && numbers[j] == m) || (numbers[j-1] == m && numbers[j] == n)) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
System.out.println(Boolean.toString(found));
```